# how to play handheld playfullscreen movie-in-aspect-ratio in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my project i have to play video.  I am using below code to play the video

```
Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie("StarWars.mp4", Color.black, 
FullScreenMovieControlMode.CancelOnInput);
```

It is playing.I have to play the video  desired aspect (in square) and also i need all options such as scrolling, playing stopping etc...

```
Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie("lt.mp4", Color.black, FullScreenMovieControlMode.Full, 
FullScreenMovieScalingMode.AspectFill);
```

The above code is  playing  in aspect ratio. But the options such as rewind,play, stop options are not available. and also it is viewed in the full screen.

It should play only in the box area.

How can i do it..